# Workload Scheduler events on version 9.4 not working after switch over in production

Tags: events, workload-scheduler

Looking at conman show cpus the state is incorrect.
%sc
CPUID RUN  NODE        LIMIT FENCE DATE  TIME    STATE   METHOD   DOMAIN

TWS1  842 *UNIX MASTER   10     0 06/14/17 09:06   I J   MDe        MDM

After JnextPlan everything is still working properly, but it is still 
reporting MDe  and not MDEA

From WAS logs

com.ibm.tws.util.jmx.JMXBrowser.getSSLAttributeList(JMXBrowser.java:391)
 at
com.ibm.tws.util.jmx.JMXBrowser.loadSSLServerConfiguration(JMXBrowser.ja
va:1078)
 at
com.ibm.tws.util.jmx.JMXBrowser.getSSLTrustFilePassword(JMXBrowser.java:
1061)
 at
com.ibm.tws.event.EIFListener.addSSLCertsProperties(EIFListener.java:668
 at
com.ibm.tws.event.EIFListener.loadServerProperties(EIFListener.java:641)
 at
com.ibm.tws.event.EIFListener.generateConfigurationFile(EIFListener.java
:310)
 at com.ibm.tws.event.EIFListener.start(EIFListener.java:163)
 at
com.ibm.tws.conn.event.engine.EventRuleEngineImpl.startEventProcessor(Ev
entRuleEngineImpl.java:638)
 at
com.ibm.tws.conn.event.engine.ConnEventRuleEngineBean.startEventProcesso
r(ConnEventRuleEngineBean.java:314)
 at
com.ibm.tws.conn.event.engine.EJSLocalStatelessConnEventRuleEngine_28e79
c7e.startEventProcessor(Unknown Source)
 at
com.ibm.tws.conn.event.engine.ConnEventRuleEngineEjbLocalImpl.startEvent
Processor(ConnEventRuleEngineEjbLocalImpl.java:245)
 at
com.ibm.tws.cli.events.command.StartEventProcCommand.execute(StartEventP
rocCommand.java:116)

Workload Scheduler is running, but events are not triggering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help understand the state
The STATE field has a lowercase e
If the STATE field has a lower case e, the event processor is installed
but not running. Start the event processor using the conman startevtproc
command, or the Dynamic Workload Console. If you use conman, for
example, you will see the following output:
 %startevtproc
 AWSJCL528I The event processor has been started successfully.

The STATE field has no M If the STATE field has no M, monman is not
running. Start monman using the conman startmon command. You will see
the following output: %startmon
AWSBHU470I A startmon command was issued for CPU_MASTER. The STATE field
has no D

### Resolution 1

1) make sure that value if the event processor port is wrong into the
database
db2 => select mpr_value from mdl.mpr_model_properties
where mpr_name='EVPROC_HTTPS_PORT'

This returns the event processor https port, that should
be something like 31116, but in this error case it could be 0 or -1.

2) If the value is wrong, we have to
save the correct value. Run wastools/showHostProperties.sh to retrieve
the value of httpsPort (suppose it is 31116).

3) Update the database: db2 => UPDATE MDL.MPR_MODEL_PROPERTIES SET
MPR_VALUE='31116' WHERE MPR_NAME='EVPROC_HTTPS_PORT'

4) The change will take effect at next JnextPlan.
In order to apply the change immediately, make sure if
Carry Forward is
set to ALL (run "optman ls" to get the value of cf value).
If it is not set to ALL take note of its value and run the following

optman chg cf = ALL

5) run JnextPlan -for 0000

6) if Carry Forward was not set to ALL revert its value
to the original value with optman chg cf =

7) updateWas.sh -user  -password

where the user is the primary admin id (TWS admin user).

The user specified in useropts file should be the user
defined as WAS primary admin id in security.xml file.
These are the steps to perform:
- login as tws_user
- remove the file useropts_tws_user
- in order to recreate the file, launch "composer sc" :
you will be asked to specify a username and
a password. Please specify the the primary admin id
 as user and its password.
- now run "conman stopeventprocessor"
- run "conman starteventprocessor"

If problem still occurs,
Check if the planman command has an issue:  planman showinfo
Check /etc/TWA/twainstanceX.TWA.properties file to see if EWas_basePath
is correct. (Default is /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer)
If each of the above has no issue, then truss the problematic command
using the following syntax:
truss -o /tmp/truss_conman.out conman "stopappserver;wait"
Check the truss_conman.out output file and look for an error similar to
this:

/1: stat("/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer", 0xFFFFFD7FFFDEFB00) Err#13
EACCES
[file_dac_search]
/1: write(2, " A W S B H U 6 2 6 W   T".., 76) = 76

### Resolution part 2

Consult with your UNIX system administrator to investigate the cause for
the Operation System level error code 13.

Compare the /opt
/opt/IBM
/opt/IBM/WebSphere

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
- and their sub-directories' permissions against a working environment to correct the permissions

Correct permissions should look like the following.
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  root 4096 Apr  8  2015 ibm
drwxr-xr-x  18 root  root 4096 Oct  3  2016 IBM

drwxr-x---  2 root  root 4096 Apr 17 12:34 CAP
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  root 4096 Jan 15  2016 IMShared
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root 4096 Apr 13  2015 InstallationManager
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root 4096 Apr 13  2015 ISA
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root 4096 Jun 21 15:12 JazzSM
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root 4096 Apr  8  2015 tsamp
drwxr-xr-x  2 m92   root 4096 Mar  1 09:59 TWA
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root 4096 May 24 12:18 TWAUI
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root 4096 Aug  6  2015 WebSphere

drwxr-xr-x 37 root root 4096 Jun 21 15:11 AppServer